# How to manage networkpolicy of kubernetes

Tags: web, kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I don`t know what tools can manage networkpolicy of kubernetes, such as web UI, or some opensource software.
Someone can give me some advices? Thanks!

Comment: Vi + YAML will do it my dude.

Answer (score 1):

Try [NetworkPolicy Editor](https://editor.cilium.io/) which will enable you to Create, Visualize, and Share Kubernetes NetworkPolicies. Another great blog https://cilium.io/blog/2021/02/10/network-policy-editor to know more about this netpol visualiser.